# Converting R.java variable to URI

Tags: android, uri

Is this possible converting R.java variable to URI reference?
What can be URI?

PS: So silly question I know. But thanks for your kind helps..

Comment: Your question is a little unclear - what are you trying to do, and what have you tried already?

Comment: If I create an xml inside res folder, it'll be created reference into R.java file. Can I convert these references to URI? What can be convert to URI? A variable reference is unique and URI is too. Can I call variables with URI?

Comment: [Here you go!](http://androidbook.blogspot.com/2009/08/referring-to-android-resources-using.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean that you're storing URIs as string values in an xml file, and need to convert those into `java.net.URI` objects?

If so...

In an xml file called `uris.xml`

```
<resources>
    <string name="stackoverflow">http://www.stackoverflow.com</string>
</resources>
```

And then in your Java code you can use

```
import java.net.URI;

URI stackoverflowUri = new URI(getResources().getString(R.uri.stackoverflow));
```

(you'll need to add code to catch any `URISyntaxException` thrown by the `new URI` call)

Comment: Thank you so much. I was looking for get access to `uris.xml` file which is inside the `res/raw` folder by using URI. This is the simple tutorial to get access anything which is referenced inside of R.java file. I thought URI and R.java references are unique and they can be map one to another. Your tutorial and @Knickedi's link are very good to understand that. Thank you again.